# Participation of Jewish Red Army Soldiers in Rape/Atrocities in Germany?

Tags: world-war-two, soviet-union, jews

I recall reading but not where I read it that soldiers of Jewish extraction or actual Jews tended to avoid the excesses of the Red Army once German civilians were encountered. Is there any evidence of or explanation for this restraint?

Comment: I do not think there is any statistics separating criminals according to their ethnic/religious origin. Therefore, this question is unanswerable, and I vote to close.

Comment: Some historians work with interviews of witnesses exclusively. Looking at personal recordings of a few persons is totally customary. You can't expect statistic significance to be present for every possible question.

Answer (score 16):

You may have read this in Antony Beevor's book *The Fall of Berlin 1945* where he writes:

> And a wide range of anecdotal evidence indicates that Red Army
>   officers who were Jewish went out of their way to protect German women
>   and girls.

Anecdotal evidence is as much as one can expect under the circumstances - the Red Army's image was of paramount importance and such crimes, while discouraged, were all too often ignored or swept under the carpet.

The only piece of direct evidence I've found is from Vasily Grossman's *A Writer at War*. Grossman, a Jew, was "a special correspondent for the Red Army newspaper, Krasnaya Zvezda, or Red Star" and "proved to be the most perceptive and honest eyewitness of the Soviet frontlines between 1941 and 1945." Referring to the 8th Guards Army in the town of Schwerin, Grossman writes:

> Women’s screams are heard from open windows. A Jewish officer, whose
>   whole family was killed by Germans, is billeted in the apartment of a
>   Gestapo man who has escaped. The women and girls [left behind] are
>   safe while he is there. When he leaves, they all cry and plead with
>   him to stay.

As to why Jewish soldiers might have been less inclined than their Red Army colleagues to participate in such atrocities, there are two plausible (but by no means definitive) explanations:

- [Jewish soldiers](https://www.ucis.pitt.edu/nceeer/2011_824-03g_Gitelman.pdf) were very conscious of the [perception that they were bad soldiers](https://www.timesofisrael.com/yad-vashem-marks-diversity-bravery-of-red-army-jews/) - cowards, weak, etc. Adding 'rapist' to the list would not have improved their image and they were motivated to prove their bravery and military professionalism, showing that they could fight. That Jewish soldiers did fight with distinction is evidenced by the fact that they were awarded a disproportionately high number of medals relative their numbers.
- In his book, Beevor relates that many incidents of rape were fueled by alcohol. Martin McKee (*[Alcohol in Russia](https://academic.oup.com/alcalc/article/34/6/824/192703)*) and R. J. Simon (*[In the Golden Land](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=GN54aY1YVigC&pg=PA54&lpg=PA54&dq=soviet%20jews%20and%20alcohol&source=bl&ots=EVruL5eAYN&sig=0tNo4ndF9jYgy-kk5WchI9urxzw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjKzcjem4PYAhVJv5QKHUkjDzQQ6AEIYjAJ#v=onepage&q=alcohol&f=false)*) note that incidents of alcohol abuse among Soviet Jews were lower than among Slavs, and Simon adds that spouse abuse was also less common.

Neither of the above explanations mean that Jewish soldiers did not participate in atrocities, but they could account for the apparently greater 'restraint' shown.

Comment: Thanks for identifying source. No idea why Jews would be the special protectors of Germans. Maybe propaganda, maybe an isolated incident or maybe some other reason and it is true.

Comment: Not special protectors, I think, perhaps just more conscious of military professionalism.

Comment: Even with the citations, it remains totally unclear as to why Jewish officers would in any way or form be more or less inclined to retaliatory or protective behavior than the average Red Army officer.

Comment: Maybe because of a different upbringing with respect to religion or family/social background. Maybe because of a higher education due to social background.

Comment: I'm not sure about education preventing rape or attrocities though... Might have to Google up what education is.

Comment: The sources are not saying that education prevented rape but rather that officers were less likely to commit rape (and that educated people were more likely to be officers) - that's not the same as saying that education prevented rape. Officers may have been less likely to commit rape partly because they were there to carry out orders and they had been ordered to prevent rape. Also (though I'm just guessing here), they might have feared being reported as they would be more easily identifiable.

Comment: Also, I would refer back to my first comment about professionalism. The sources are saying that Jewish soldiers were very focused on fighting to counter accusations of cowardice etc. How would they prove their courage by raping women?

Comment: @LarsBosteen you mean they also could've been worried about how the home front in the Soviet Union perceived them?

Comment: Lars, please note that most of your arguments are merely about *officers*,  and how little about *Jewish* soldiers (as per the question). The link your arguments provide are *very* thin; perhaps you should cut the answer after the second quote, as I feel the rest is *very much* speculative, to say the least.

Comment: @DevSolar. I've read through your and other comments (which are appreciated as I'm looking to make the answer as accurate as possible) and looking elsewhere to get a broader picture. I'll be making some revisions but it'll take a few hours. Thanks for your input.

Comment: 1. Jews were not bad soldiers. Nor they were percepted as such. They were simply disliked often. A Jew was almost a communist, but not protected as a communist. And soldiers, mostly villagers, hated communists. 2. Practically all men returned from the war as alcoholics, having 100ml of hard alcohol for a day. All of them  drunk, Jew or not Jew. 3. The post seems to me as some talk about nothing. No statistics here, and so, no significant info. These are not arguments for anything.

Comment: @Gangnus Can you back up your claims? Statistics are preferred...

Comment: @jjack I see one more openly nationalistic question and the same answer. No serious arguments, no statistics. That is twice more than enough for me. wouldn't you like to address to somebody else? What should I support by evidence? The demands of logic? No, thanks. If somebody is interested, let him return to the school program.

Comment: @Gangnus. Your points: 1. Check my post, I never said Jews were bad soldiers (actually, I said they fought with distinction). I also gave sources for the perception issue - here is another: A. Weiner, 'Making Sense of War'. 2. 'Practically all men returned from the war as alcoholics', 'all of them drunk' - pretty big assertions. Alcohol was certainly a big issue in the Red Army but 'practically all' and 'all of them drunk' - is this 'logic' which needs no statistics? 3. You are entitled to your opinion.